# Hibernate search do a filter search on two different tables

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

here's my problem.

I have two indexed models ACL and Asset. There is no real link between these two tables instead of the ID of an ACL object is the same than the Asset object.

With HQL, I have this request how works perfectly:

```
String[] permissions
Query query = session.createQuery("From Asset as asset, "
+ "Acl as acl "
+ "where asset.id = :id and asset.id = acl.object.id "
+ AclService.buildQuery (permissions)
+ "and acl.group in (:groups) ");
query.setParameter("id", assetId);
query.setParameterList("groups", user.getGroup().getGroups().values());


public static String buildQuery(String[] perms) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(); 
    for (int i=0; i<perms.length; i++) {
        buf.append("and ");
        buf.append(perms[i]);
        buf.append(" = true ");

    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

I want to do the same database request, but by using Hibernate Search. How can I do this. I already looked this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-filter but I wasn't able to produce good results.

How can I do it exactly?

Comment: How do you index ACL and Asset? What have you tried? Most likely you would need to index both classes into the same index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hardy is saying, you need a combined index of the two entities. Hibernate Search does not support (query time) index joining at this point.

Check out the section dealing with the [indexing of associated entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-mapping-associated) in the reference guide. The `@IndexEmbedded` and `ContainedIn` annotations can be used for that.

Comment: After using @indexEmbedded, am I be able to use a filter to keep only some  objetcs?

Comment: Yes, though the primary means of selecting the results would be predicates in the [query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-building-lucene-queries).